# Ionic Firebase analytics custom parameters

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-analytics, ionic5

In my ionic5 app I am sending events like so

```
export class Logger extends FirebaseAnalytics{

...

aFunction(tapTarget: string){

    const logData = {target: tapTarget};
    this.log(EventType.TAP, logData);
}
```

Based on [this](https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics#logeventname-params)

but I do not see the event parameters in my firebase console? I see the events but not the payload that the app is sending... ?
Is there a magic setting on firebase console to see those values?
Or is the code above not working?

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to `extend` *FirebaseAnalytics*.
You must `inject` it in your constructor.

```ts
import { FirebaseAnalytics } from '@ionic-native/firebase-analytics/ngx';
```

```ts
constructor(private firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics) {}
```

```ts
this.firebaseAnalytics.logEvent('event_name', {param: 'value'})
  .then((res: any) => console.log(res))
  .catch((error: any) => console.error(error));
```

Make sure the `Ionic Native` wrapper is installed alongside the `Cordova` plugin itself.

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics
npm install @ionic-native/firebase-analytics
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. But extending actually works. I see the app traffic in the firebase console. However, I do not see the custom parameters. Maybe it is in fact an issue with the `extend` so I will give your suggetion a shot. Thanks! :)